# how to close slide div without hidden the setting icon when click outside the div in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm implementing slide div for creating theme color. It works fine but when I click the outside it's not closing that div and I tried a lot but not working my code so help me out for this..and I research many resources from the internet I got, but don't know how to implement this. here is my code

```
function clickedThemebtn() {
  var ele = document.getElementsByClassName("theme-colors")[0];

  if (ele.classList.contains("shown")) {
    ele.classList.remove("shown");
  } else {
    ele.classList.add("shown");
  }
}
```

Here is my fiddle you can [Check Here](https://jsfiddle.net/1kxfmv5q/)

Answer (score 0):

You can attach an event listener to the document, that it triggers the close event. Keep in mind that the following will hide the menu when you click anywhere inside the menu. You need further checks to prevent it.

```
function clickedThemebtn(e) {

    var ele = document.getElementsByClassName("theme-colors")[0];
    // If the click is outside of the button, remove the class
    if (e.target.id === "slideBtn") {
    if (ele.classList.contains("shown")) {
      ele.classList.remove("shown");
    } else {
      ele.classList.add("shown");
    }
    return;
  }
  // all other cases: outside the button
  ele.classList.remove("shown");    
}

document.addEventListener('click', clickedThemebtn);
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c0zgdwpv/)

Here's a jQuery solution since the fiddle had jQuery [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tpe461by/)

Comment: What you mean that when i click inside the slide then it will close that div..?

Comment: @DeveloperLion, check the fiddle. Click on the button, and then on a color button. You will see the effect.

Comment: Some time it not opening ?? Why

Comment: plz...give me other solution for this

Answer (score 0):

Please check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h29nwLs5/4/) out. 
My approach here was to add an fixed positioned div which will occupy the entire screen and it will handle clicking outside.

HTML Outline

```
<div class='toggleclickoutside' onClick="handleOutsideClick()"></div>
<div id="toggleshown" class="theme-colors">...</div>
```

JS handler for outside click

```
function handleOutsideClick() {
  var ele = document.getElementsByClassName("theme-colors")[0];

  if (ele.classList.contains("shown")) {
     ele.classList.remove("shown");
  }
}
```

Css for new div

```
.toggleclickoutside{
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Any other solution for this..plz...update the answers

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to listen for the click event on the `document` object, then check if the click was within the theme selector before closing it.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', handleDocumentClick);

function handleDocumentClick(event) {
  const themeSelector = getThemeSelector();
  if (!themeSelector.contains(event.target)) {
    hideThemeSelector();
  }
}

function getThemeSelector() {
  return document.getElementsByClassName("theme-colors")[0];
}

function hideThemeSelector() {
  const themeSelector = getThemeSelector();
  themeSelector.classList.remove("shown");
}

function showThemeSelector() {
  const themeSelector = getThemeSelector();
  themeSelector.classList.add("shown");
}
```

Note that I added a few handy functions for convenience sake.

I updated your fiddle and now it looks like this: https://jsfiddle.net/0nqzpyko/